# Why can't forward declared friend class be referred in the class?

Tags: c++, friend

The following code doesn't compile:

```
struct X {
  friend class Y;
  Y* ptr;
};
```

The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) describes the situation as

> ... If the name of the class that is used in the friend declaration is
>   not yet declared, it is forward declared on the spot.

If the "spot" means where the friend relationship is declared, then it should be fine to declare the member `Y* ptr`. Why doesn't it compile? Where in the standard prohibits this?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy MSVC being able to compile something isn't the best of tests.  both Clang and GCC fail to compile.

Comment: Please provide the specific compiler errors that you are seeing along with what compiler and version you are using.

Comment: Ahh, that's not what "spot" means.

Comment: [Minimal (non-)Compilable Verifiable Example with gcc and clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/717e154281997168)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a mistake on the site. It contradicts the standard, which says that friendship declaration is not a substitute for a forward declaration:

> 7.3.1.2.3 Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that namespace. If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup or qualified lookup.

The part about the name not being visible to unqualified or qualified lookup essentially means that the name does not behave like a forward declaration.

Comment: So if you put `class Y;` before the `friend class Y;` at that point the class `Y` is declared and can then be used.

Comment: @RichardChambers but it would declare class Y that is local to X, not Y in the surrounding namespace.

Comment: @n.m. so the `class Y;` would need to be at whatever scope the class definition is located.

Comment: @RichardChambers, yes. However, IMO, it's poor coding practice to use the `friend` declaration to also declare a class. It will be better to delcare the class first before using the `friend` declaration.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, but you have to be careful: putting `class Y;` inside `X` declares `class X::Y`, i.e. a local class, not a global class, i.e. `class ::Y`. To see an example of what I mean fork from [this demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/B7nKtX), then uncomment line 19, and compile again; you'll see a compile error.

Comment: I suspect what the quoted sentence is trying to say is that you don't need a forward declaration in order to declare a friend, it's implicitly forward-declared for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of @dasblinkenlight, a note in [3.3.2 Point of declaration lit. 10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.scope.pdecl#10) explicitly says that a friend declaration does not introduce (and therefore not "forward declare") a class name:

> 10 [ Note: Friend declarations refer to functions or classes that are
>   members of the nearest enclosing namespace, but they do not introduce
>   new names into that namespace ([namespace.memdef]).

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this code is to simply [add `class` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier):

```
struct X {
    friend class Y;
    class Y* ptr;
};
```

This will forward declare `class Y` at the global scope, if `X` is in the global scope.

Comment: This will not "forward declare" anything, as it does not make it possible to use the name `Y` alone like a real declaration would. This makes `Y` a member of the global scope only if `X` is also directly in the global scope. More generally, that code will twice use the `Y` which is associated with the innermost enclosing namespace or block scope.

Comment: @aschepler It was assumed that `X` was in the global scope, I refined my answer. Could you please explain your first sentence? What is the difference between `class Y; struct X { friend class Y; Y* ptr; };` and the code in my answer?