# C++, "friend class" that's defined in the same header

Tags: c++

I'm following [this tutorial](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns) to create a simple iterator, although they are iterating primitive int, I'm iterating an object type `SpamValue`.

I have class called `SpamValue` and another called `SpamValueStackIter` and they are tightly coupled, because I didn't want to expose a lot of getters, so I made one class `SpamValueStackIter` a "`friend` class" in `SpamValue` header.

```
#ifndef SPAMSTACK_H
#define SPAMSTACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include "SpamValue.h"
using namespace std; 

class SpamStack
{

public:
    friend class  SpamValueStackIter; 
    SpamStack(SpamValue** SpamValueItems, int size)
    {
        _position =-1; 
        _total_size = size;
        _SpamValueItems = new SpamValue*[_total_size];
         int i=0;
        for (; i<_total_size; i++)
        {
        this->_SpamValueItems[i] = SpamValueItems[i];
        }
    }
    ~SpamStack()
    {
         if (NULL!=_SpamValueItems)
                   {
                         /*delete each*/
                   int i =0;  
                   for  (; i<_total_size; i++)
                   {
                       if (NULL!=_SpamValueItems[i])
                       {
                            delete  _SpamValueItems[i];
                       }
                   }
                     /*delete the array*/
                    delete [] _SpamValueItems;
                   }
    }
    /*push*/
    void push(SpamValue* SpamValue)
    {
        _SpamValueItems[++_position];
    }
    /*pop*/
    SpamValue* pop()
    {
        return  _SpamValueItems[_position--];
    }
    /*isEmpty*/
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return (_position == -1);
    }
    /*getters*/
    SpamValue** getSpamValueItems()
    {
        return  this->_SpamValueItems;  
    }
    int getTotalSize()
    {
        return _total_size; 
    }
     SpamValueStackIter* createIterator()const; 

private:
    SpamValue** _SpamValueItems; 
    int _total_size; 
    int _position; 


};


class SpamValueStackIter
{
    const SpamStack* _stack; 
    int _index; 

public:
    SpamValueStackIter(const SpamStack *s)
    {
        _stack = s; 

    }
    /*set index position to first item*/
    void first()
    {
        _index = 0; 
    }
    /*set index position to the next item in the iterator*/
    void next()
    {
        _index++; 
    }
    /*is the iteration completed */
    bool isDone()
    {
        return _index == _stack->_position + 1; 
    }
    /* return the current item */
    SpamValue* currentItem()
    {
        return _stack->_SpamValueItems[index];
    }

    /*create a new iterator*/
    SpamValueStackIter* SpamStack::createIterator()const
    {
        return new SpamValueStackIter(this);
    }



};
#endif /* SPAMSTACK_H*/
```

In the SpamStack.h:, Im getting this error:

```
SpamStack.h:77:6: error: ‘SpamValueStackIter’ does not name a type
      SpamValueStackIter* createIterator()const;
```

And also:

```
SpamStack.h:121:52: error: cannot define member function ‘SpamStack::createIterator                                                                                                             tor’ within ‘SpamValueStackIter’
     SpamValueStackIter* SpamStack::createIterator()const
```

Why can't `SpamStack` resolve the "`friend` class" that's defined in the same header?

**After forward declaration, as suggested by others:**

```
#ifndef SPAMSTACK_H
#define SPAMSTACK_H
#include <iostream>
#include "SpamValue.h"
using namespace std; 

/*forward declare*/
class  SpamValueStackIter; 
class SpamStack
{

public:
    friend class  SpamValueStackIter; 
    SpamStack(SpamValue** SpamValueItems, int size)
    {
        _position =-1; 
        _total_size = size;
        _SpamValueItems = new SpamValue*[_total_size];
         int i=0;
        for (; i<_total_size; i++)
        {
        this->_SpamValueItems[i] = SpamValueItems[i];
        }
    }
    ~SpamStack()
    {
         if (NULL!=_SpamValueItems)
                   {
                         /*delete each*/
                   int i =0;  
                   for  (; i<_total_size; i++)
                   {
                       if (NULL!=_SpamValueItems[i])
                       {
                            delete  _SpamValueItems[i];
                       }
                   }
                     /*delete the array*/
                    delete [] _SpamValueItems;
                   }
    }
    /*push*/
    void push(SpamValue* SpamValue)
    {
        _SpamValueItems[++_position];
    }
    /*pop*/
    SpamValue* pop()
    {
        return  _SpamValueItems[_position--];
    }
    /*isEmpty*/
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return (_position == -1);
    }
    /*getters*/
    SpamValue** getSpamValueItems()
    {
        return  this->_SpamValueItems;  
    }
    int getTotalSize()
    {
        return _total_size; 
    }

    SpamValueStackIter* createIterator()const; 

private:
    SpamValue** _SpamValueItems; 
    int _total_size; 
    int _position; 


};

class SpamValueStackIter
{


public:
    SpamValueStackIter(const SpamStack *s)
    {
        _stack = s; 

    }
    /*set index position to first item*/
    void first()
    {
        _index = 0; 
    }
    /*set index position to the next item in the iterator*/
    void next()
    {
        _index++; 
    }
    /*is the iteration completed */
    bool isDone()
    {
        return _index == _stack->_position + 1; 
    }
    /* return the current item */
    SpamValue* currentItem()
    {
        return _stack->_SpamValueItems[index];
    }



private:
      const SpamStack* _stack;
      int _index; 


};
```

/*create a new iterator*/
        SpamValueStackIter* SpamStack::createIterator()const
        {
            return new SpamValueStackIter(this);
        }

```
#endif /* SPAMSTACK_H */
```

**In getting this error now:**

```
SpamStack.h:117:45: error: invalid types ‘SpamValue** const[<unresolved overloaded function type>]’ for array subscript
         return _stack->_SpamValueItems[index];
```

Comment: You need to forward declare `class SpamValueStackIter;` *before* defining `class SpamStack`.

Comment: Mostly duplicate: [Why can't forward declared friend class be referred in the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044848/why-cant-forward-declared-friend-class-be-referred-in-the-class). Asks a different question, but gets the exact same answer.

Comment: @cigien, thanks for advice however that did not work. Im getting undeclared/undefined errors now in SpamStack, after forward declaring it became a chicken or egg problem...I'm going to just declare these in separate classes & call it a day.

Comment: It did work. Unfortunately you had more bugs. Can't reproduce the new error. You may have left something out and your example does not exactly duplicate the code you are using. I get *'index' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_index'?*, and when I follow the compiler's advice and use `_index` no error. A couple of compiler warnings in both cases. Definitely fix this one: *warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]* over `_SpamValueItems[++_position];`.